# Difference between Object.var- - and Object.var-=1?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, assert

Today I encountered a strange warning by my IDE, for one piece of code and no warning for another (supposedly identical) code.
The following piece of code says the if condition is always false:

```
public void foo(Node n) {
    assert(n.var > 0);
    n.var--;
    if (n.var == 0) {
         // do stuff
    }
}
```

While the following works without any warnings:

```
public void foo(Node n) {
    assert(n.var > 0);
    n.var -= 1;
    if (n.var == 0) {
         // do stuff
    }
}
```

With the following class:

```
public class Node {
    private int var;
}
```

While the first warning is obviously nonsense, I was wondering if there is actually a difference between `var--` and `var-=1`..?
And is this actually a warning specific to my IDE? If not, tell me in the comments and I will edit this post accordingly.

Comment: What is the initial value of `var`?

Comment: Unknown. It comes straight from the method header

Comment: You should probably include the method header in your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: as suggested, i added the header

Comment: I think what you see here is an error in intellij's code logic analyzer. You should construct a small self-contained example, and file a bug report.

Comment: Show us the minimum source file that actually produces the warning. The problem is most likely in some piece you "simplified" out when posting.

Comment: @user2357112 I shamefully admit that I simplified the code too much and what I posted didn't actually give me a warning. I updated the code and this one *actually does* give the warning, but the fact that the problem didn't arise earlier confuses me even more.. I added the relevant pieces to the question title

Comment: How do you create the `Node` object to pass to each method? How do you initialize the `n` member variable? Please provide a **complete** example which exactly reproduces the warning and which we can just copy and paste to see for ourselves.

Comment: If I copy the code above to an empty project, intelliJ gives me the warning. it doesn't matter if the method is actually ever called, the warning is shown in any case.  ut as suggested by daslinkenlight, it is probably a bug in the IDEs code analyser and as long as no more promising answer comes along, I will file a bug report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in IntelliJ IDEA. I've filed it as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151355, you can watch it to be notified of its progress.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that

```
int var = 1;
int x = (var -= 1); // x == 0
```

and

```
int x = var--; // x == 1 as the -- is post decrement.
```

Note: the difference is largely a matter of style as a stand alone statement. I prefer the shorter `x--` or `x++` to `x-=1` / `x+=-1` or `x+=1`

Comment: Of course, anyone who writes code this way should be shot.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice side effects should always be kept to a minimum.

Comment: thanks for the post, although the question kinda changed in the meantime (i guess.. did it?), because the problem only arises for members of a class

Comment: @Neuron IntelliJ has a lot of warnings, some of them helpful, some of them are stylistic things where some people prefer one approach or the other e.g. some are contradictory to allow people to choose what they prefer.

Comment: if no other explanation comes up in the next couple of hours (which I guess will be the case), I'll up vote your answer

Comment: @Neuron You can upvote as many answers as you like, you can only *accept* one at a time thought.

Comment: that's what I meant! ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Peter Lawrey say:

```
x = var--  Means:  Step1: x = var; Step2 :var = var - 1;
var-=1 Means: Step1 ： int temp = var - 1; Step2 : var = temp;
```